# Need resource to configure my magento REST Apis

Tags: product, customer, api, rest-api, soap-api-v2

I am here to know the step by step configuration of magento RESTful apis.
I have basic idea of how it works. But Still I dont know to configure the api to produce the results.
Help me to configure it from scratch.

Comment: What do you mean by from scratch? http://www.magentocommerce.com/api/rest/introduction.html Set up user/password and then give it a go with a OAuth bib of your choice. What EXACTLY is your problem?

Comment: Actually, Whenever I am trying visit this url [http://localhost/magento/api/rest/products] Its showing, <b> Invalid webservice adapter specified.</b>
I just checked for multiviews in .htaccess, But its not there. 
I am wondering how to configure the whole rest api.

Answer (score 1):

In the `catalog/etc/api.xml` it seems like, there is no product resource. I would dig in the

```
\Mage_Api_Model_Server::initialize
```

and check why this happens.

If I read the code correctly, there needs to be a product node here `/config/api/rest/mapping` `app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/etc/api.xml:744` but there is no.

Comment: Yes. Thanks for ur response. Can u send me any links to configure magento rest-api. Coz, I am a beginner in api configuration of magento . Thanks. Again.

Comment: I never used the API, sirry.